# firebase performance monitoring for simultaneous users

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-performance

I'm curious about fire base performance monitoring.

If 1,000 simultaneous users click one button at a time, such as ticket reservation, how much will the performance deteriorate?

Is there a way I can test that?

Thank you.

Comment: The question is very broad as we don't know what 'click one button at a time' means in your code. What does that do? Also, Firebase is a suite of products ranging from Cloud Firestore to Cloud Functions and all of those products do different things. Lastly, we don't know what is meant by 'performance' - of your App? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include your code and we'll take a look.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.